# Force computation on IEEE float/double

Tags: arithmetic

I'm checking two different procedures that will eventually be used with regular floating point arithmetic. I need to estimate numerical error arising from floating point arithmetic.

Is there a way to force computation on floating point numbers?
Model problem could be error estimation for:

`Erf[x] - Erf[x+h]`

for small vaues of $h$ and large values of $x$.

Comment: How about if you try setting `$MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision; $MaxPrecision = $MachinePrecision;` before the computation. Will this do what you want? if you give a MWE and what output you expect, I could try it. You can put the above inside a `Block` also.

Comment: @MichaelE2 that's the whole point here. Sometimes it's more accurate to find this difference directly and sometimes it's better to approximate by series in $h$. I'm trying to investigate when each method is better, so I need both arbitrary precision arithmetic for correct result and floating to check numerical errors.